# Regex to match integers between specific set of characters

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace all integers after and before these specific characters: `( ) * - / % + space` but nothing than these.

So `(34 +` should match but `a34 +` or `k3-` should not.

I have this so far, `'/(?:-| |\(|\)|\+|\*|\/|%)(\d+)(?:-| |\(|\)|\+|\*|\/|%)/'` but this is not working like what I want it to.

```
$pattern = '/[- ()+*\/%](\d+)[- ()+*\/%]/';
$replacement = "xyz($1)";
$insideFunc = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $insideFunc);
```

`$insideFunc = "float y = 45*(3-max(3-float(ceil(3)), 3-float(floor(3))))*2.302585092994046"`

`output -> float y =xyz(45)xyz(3)maxxyz(3)float(ceilxyz(3)),xyz(3)float(floorxyz(3))))*2.302585092994046`

I want it to be, `float y = xyz(45)*(xyz(3)-max(xyz(3)-float(ceil(xyz(3))), xyz(3)-float(floor(xyz(3)))))*2.302585092994046`

Comment: Use character classes instead: `[- ()+*\/%](\d+)[- ()+*\/%]` can you explain what it does that you don't want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it like that and it's working now.

```
$pattern = '/([- ()+*\/%])(\d+)([- ()+*\/%])/';
$replacement = "$1float($2)$3";
```